# R Markdown: Error message when knit

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to prepare a R Markdown document.

I wrote this chunk (see below). It works when I press the  *Run Current Chunk* button or press **Alt+Ctrl+C**. But it got an error message (see below) when I press **Knit Word** button. Appreciate any helps.

````
```{r}
data1 <- data

data_hill <- subset(data1,KAWASAN=="Hill"|KAWASAN=="hill")
data_low <- subset(data1,KAWASAN=="Lowland")
data_bank <- subset(data1,KAWASAN=="Riverbank")

```
````

> Quitting from lines 37-43 (Preview-cf0fba3251.Rmd)
>   Error in subset.default(data1, KAWASAN == "Hill" | KAWASAN == "hill") :  object 'KAWASAN' not found 
>   Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> subset -> subset.default
>   Execution halted

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with `knitr`.  `object 'KAWASAN' not found` means that `data1` does not have a column named `KAWASAN`.

Answer (score 0):

As Richie says, it means you don't have that column, a possible reason is that although you create data1 in the target .Rmd the column KAWASAN is created in a different .Rmd - for reproducibility knitr operates separately so doesn't have access to things in your workspace.

Comment: But I've tried the chunk, and it produce the following results.

Comment: But I've tried the chunk, using the same .Rmd file and it produce the results that KAWASAN is in data1.

Comment: I've able to run the analysis. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ARKassim could you say what the issue was?